# Generic array as parameter in method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, generic-programming

I'm trying to convert a `string[]` to a more generic type. The answer is probably simple, but I can't figure it out now.

My problem is that I have a method `genericMethod()` that takes an SQL query as the first parameter, so it would initially look like this: `genericMethod(string)`.

But the SQL query takes in some parameters too and that differs depending on how I need to use the SQL query.

One query can look like this:

```
genericMethod($@"
SELECT [CustomerId], COUNT (*) , MAX (OrderDate) FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [ProductType] = @0
AND ([OrderDate] > DATEADD(DAY, -@1, GETUTCDATE()))"
, productType, myChosenDate);
```

Meaning that the array-param consist of string and int.

But in another situation it would look something like this:

```
genericMethod($@"
SELECT [CustomerId], COUNT (*) , MAX (OrderDate) FROM [MyTable]
WHERE ([OrderDate] > DATEADD(DAY, -@1, GETUTCDATE()))"
, myChosenDate);
```

Meaning that the array-param only consist of an int.

And a third the parameters would be string (for the query), and then 1 to N string parameters for the query, which is the one I am using right now.

Example of the third usage:

```
genericMethod($@"
SELECT [CustomerId], COUNT (*) , MAX (OrderDate) FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [ProductType] = @0
WHERE [Manufacturer] = @1
AND ([OrderDate] > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETUTCDATE()))"
, productType, manufacturer);
```

Hope that makes sense.

The way I've solved it so far is by using `genericMethod(string, string[] params)`, but as you can see I want the last parameter to be more generic, so that the array can consist of both strings and int and not only strings.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not passing in a Dictionary<string, object> which has all the parameter names and their respective values?

Comment: Oh and you don't need the parameter names as well, why not getting it as `params object[] parameters`

Comment: @OguzOzgul hmm can you please provide an example? Sounds pretty simple

Comment: If you can share the code of your genericMethod(string, string[]), yes. Actually it is just changing the string[] to object[] (or params object[] parameters)

Comment: Seems to me like you're attempting to re-invent the wheel. Looks like you need to look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper),

Comment: @OguzOzgul ah sorry - of course! It works! Thanks a lot - can you please provide it as an answer?

Comment: @ZoharPeled that was clearly not the intention and with my little coding knowledge I knew there was a fairly simple and already useful answer out there. Thanks

Comment: Dear @badaboomskey EF or Dapper or any modern ORM tool will help you to write strongly-typed, cross-rdbm SQL queries. No need for an answer